# Is there a way to add a field to the title page in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

I have to add a `\supervisor` field to the title page of my presentation. Is there a way to do that in beamer?

I tried adding the *supervisor* information to the `\author` field, but the content of the author field are also displayed on the footer of all  the slides, and I wanted just my name to be there. If adding a field is not possible is there 
a way to display custom text at the footer?

Comment: I am not (yet?) a beamer user, but if you look at `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` you will find a command beginning `\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{default}[1][]` that seems to hold the definition of the title page template. You might be able to modify it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do the following:

`\author[Your Name]{Your Name\\{\small Supervised by: Your Supervisor's Name}}`

for example.  The optional argument of `\author` is the short author, which goes in the footer.

Comment: `\small` has no effect in my beamer document, any idea?

Comment: @Rasoul Without seeing your code it's hard to tell what the problem is. The difference between `\small` and `\normalsize` isn't very much. If you try `\author[Your Name]{Your Name\\{\small Supervised by: Your Supervisor's Name}\\Supervised by: Your Supervisor's Name}` you should see that the first line is shorter than the second line, showing that the `\small` is having the correct effect.

Comment: @AlanMunn The `\small` effect is indeed not very noticeable. Is there a way to add a field so I can define the font size?