# Adding a new field to the title page in beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

I just read a question about adding a new field to a title page in beamer ([Is there a way to add a field to the title page in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8975/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-field-to-the-title-page-in-beamer)). I have exactly the same question, and the proposed answer is efficient. However, it doesn't provide a method to define a new field.

Let's say I want to add a `\supervisor` field to a lot of presentations, with a specific color and font. I would like not to do so in the `\author` field each time.

I tried to alter `\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{default}[1][]` in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`, unsuccessfully (my skills are limited for such alterations).

Is there a way to add a new field to the title page?

PS : I know I should have commented the original post for such a question, however I don't have enough reputation to do so. That's why I created a new thread.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add text before or after the tile page elements via

```
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{before material}{after material}
```

Thus you can put your supervisor's name at towards the bottom of the title page via

```
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{}{\begin{center}Supervisor\end{center}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\title{Talk title}
\author{The author}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{}{\begin{center}Supervisor\end{center}}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you need to place the material in a different order between standard elements then you will need to modify the template from `beamerinnerthemeXXX.sty` where `XXX` is either default or the particular inner theme you are using.